# C# -- > Excel copy with the right format

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, number-formatting

I have a problem with the numberformat in Excel.
I have created an application with wpf. There is a *DataTable*, where I display some numbers, like prices and other values.

To export these values to Excel, I've created a .xltx which opens, when I press export. 
In my DataTable I select all cells and copy them to the clipboard. To paste it to Excel, is the PasteSpecial used.

My Problem is:
I paste the values in the german format (decimal seperator is comma and thousands seperator is a dot)
But only on one system (Windows Server 2008) the program paste it to Excel in the american format(decimal seperator dot and thousands seperator comma).

The Excel 2k10 on the Windows Server 2008 recognize the values in the german format. 
For Example:

```
Value = 1.234.567,89 (german format)
```

When I paste it via the clipboard

```
Value = 1,234 (german format)
```

The Settings on the Server are all in the german format

- decimal seperator: comma
- thousands seperator: dot

What could I else try?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410422

Comment: Couldn't try, because I have now problems with the clipboard. I response later ;-)

Comment: This solution didn't helped. But I am on going with this problem.

Comment: So I solved the problem there was an issue with a COM-AddIn from the Bluetooth-Driver